Is everything inside of src directory of Next js, server sided rendered?
I use src directory alongside of the app directory. so, the app directory, is inside of the src directory.
now, I created a folder inside of src called hooks, and this is my simple hook:
// useIsClient.js

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useIsClient() {
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsClient(true);
  }, []);

  return isClient;
}

as you can see there's no use client but if you import it inside of a client component, it will work.
I wonder if Nextjs detects the use keyword so it knows, it is not a component and it is a hook, and this is why it works or everything inside of the app directory is server-side component but not the whole src.
which one of these assumptions is true?

These are a few common questions which arse when beginning with the Next.js. Confusion between server and client components is common and normal in the beginning.
The first confusion is on the /app directory and /src directory.

Files in the app/ directory are Server Components by default unless explicitly marked as Client Components by adding "use client" at the top of the file.
But this src/ folder is a convention for better file organization. It has no special impact on whether something is server-rendered or client-rendered. Even when setting up a project it asks whether to use a src directory or not. That means it's even not necessary.

Then the next confusion is about using of hooks in client and server components.

A custom hook like useIsClient isn't automatically server-side or client-side. It depends on where you use it.

If it's used in a Client Component (declared with "use client"), it will work on the client. Conversely, it will fail if used in a Server Component, as Server Components do not support hooks like useState or useEffect.


Why Your useIsClient Hook Works in Client components ?

A user-defined hook captures some browser logic (useEffect and useState) and makes sure that the component it is called into is rendered on the client. Although the very hook doesn't have "use client", it would work because it is imported into a Client Component.

Hooks Don't Have Rendering Context on Their Own: useIsClient won't work for either server or client - it's just a plain JavaScript module. The rendering context (Server or Client) is defined only by the component that uses it.


Then according to that if you try your hook in a server component it will throw an error


// This will throw an error because Server Components cannot use hooks
import useIsClient from "@/hooks/useIsClient";

export default function ServerComponent() {
  const isClient = useIsClient(); // ❌ Error: Hooks cannot be used in Server Components

  return <div>{isClient}</div>;
}



I think this explanation will help you to understand this scenario.
